# class implementing Iterators loops

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem with implementing Iterator interface
Here is the code:

```
class User_Model_Users implements Iterator, Countable
{

    protected $_count;
    protected $_gateway;
    protected $_resultSet;

    public function __construct($results, $gateway)
    {
        $this->setGateway($gateway);
        $this->_resultSet = $results;
    }

    public function setGateway(User_Model_UserGateway $gateway)
    {
        $this->_gateway = $gateway;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getGateway()
    {
        return $this->_gateway;
    }

    public function count()
    {
        if (null === $this->_count) {
            $this->_count = count($this->_resultSet);
        }
        return $this->_count;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        if ($this->_resultSet instanceof Iterator) {
            $key = $this->_resultSet->key();
        } else {
            $key = key($this->_resultSet);
        }
        $result = $this->_resultSet [$key];
        if (!$result instanceof User_Model_User) {
            $gateway = $this->getGateway();
            $result = $gateway->createUser($result);
            $this->_resultSet [$key] = $result;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return key($this->_resultSet);
    }

    public function next()
    {
        return next($this->_resultSet);
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        return reset($this->_resultSet);
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return (bool) $this->current();
    }

}
```

As a $result I provide Zend_Db_Table_Rowset but it can be also other object or array.
How can I fix this code so that I works in a foreach loop?
I don't get any errors as it is an infinite loop.

Comment: "can be also other object or array" - in this case an example script+data and the expected result would be nice.

Comment: for now It doesn't work with Zend_Db_Table_Rowset. I'd like to solve this case

Comment: What is your question in specific? What do you think needs fixing? Which error do you get? "It doesn't work" does not say what does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess (haven't really delved into the code):

Since your implementation of valid() is

```
public function valid()
{
    return (bool) $this->current();
}
```

you should make sure that current() returns false when there are no more elements

```
public function current()
{
    if ($this->_resultSet instanceof Iterator) {
        $key = $this->_resultSet->key();
    } else {
        $key = key($this->_resultSet);
    }

    if ( is_null($key)  ) { // could also be is_null($key)||false===$key, not sure...
        return false;
    }

    $result = $this->_resultSet[$key];
    if (!$result instanceof User_Model_User) {
        $gateway = $this->getGateway();
        $result = $gateway->createUser($result);
        $this->_resultSet[$key] = $result;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and btw: your function key() doesn't implement the `instanceof Iterator` case like current() does.

---

Test script:

```
<?php
class User_Model_Users implements Iterator, Countable
{
    protected $_count;
    protected $_gateway;
    protected $_resultSet;

    public function __construct($results, $gateway)
    {
        $this->setGateway($gateway);
        $this->_resultSet = $results;
        $this->_count = null;
    }

    public function setGateway(User_Model_UserGateway $gateway)
    {
        $this->_gateway = $gateway;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getGateway()
    {
        return $this->_gateway;
    }

    public function count()
    {
        if ( is_null($this->_count) ) {
            $this->_count = count($this->_resultSet);
        }
        return $this->_count;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        if ($this->_resultSet instanceof Iterator) {
            $key = $this->_resultSet->key();
        } else {
            $key = key($this->_resultSet);
        }
        if ( is_null($key) ) {
            return false;
        }

        $result = $this->_resultSet[$key];
        if (!$result instanceof User_Model_User) {
            $gateway = $this->getGateway();
            $result = $gateway->createUser($result);
            $this->_resultSet[$key] = $result;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return key($this->_resultSet);
    }

    public function next()
    {
        return next($this->_resultSet);
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        return reset($this->_resultSet);
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return (bool) $this->current();
    }
}

class User_Model_User {
    protected $x, $y;

    public function __construct($x, $y) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }
}

class User_Model_UserGateway {
    protected $id;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->id = time();
    }

    public function createUser($x) {
        echo "User_Model_UserGateway::createUser($x)\n";
        return new User_Model_User($x, $this->id);
    }
}

$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$users = new User_Model_Users($a, new User_Model_UserGateway);
foreach($users as $u) {
    print_r($u);
}
```

prints

```
User_Model_UserGateway::createUser(a)
User_Model_User Object
(
    [x:protected] => a
    [y:protected] => 1311167311
)
User_Model_UserGateway::createUser(b)
User_Model_User Object
(
    [x:protected] => b
    [y:protected] => 1311167311
)
User_Model_UserGateway::createUser(c)
User_Model_User Object
(
    [x:protected] => c
    [y:protected] => 1311167311
)
User_Model_UserGateway::createUser(d)
User_Model_User Object
(
    [x:protected] => d
    [y:protected] => 1311167311
)
```

Comment: @greg606 Then I really need an example script because my simple test script says otherwise ;-)

Comment: I discovered the bug and it's actually inside the Zend Framework Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract class using Arrayaccess - offsetSet and offsetGet are not implemented! Thanks!